# Reset row increment before going to next worksheet

Tags: vba, loops, excel, for-loop

I have 2 workbooks. One wb acts as a database (divided into users), while the other is used to pull data from that wb based on a date. I looped the macro and at first it seems to pull data only from the first sheet. **See NOTE below**

```
Dim y As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer

r = CollateSh3.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
y = 3
WS_Count = wbLog.Worksheets.Count
For I = 1 To WS_Count
    Do Until wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("A" & y) = ""
    If wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("B" & y).Value = RequiredDate Then

        CollateSh3.Range("A" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("D" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("C" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("F" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("D" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("G" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("E" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("H" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("F" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("I" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("G" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("J" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("H" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("K" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("I" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("L" & y).Value
        CollateSh3.Range("K" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("N" & y).Value
        r = r + 1
        y = y + 1

    Else
        y = y + 1
    End If
    Loop

    'MsgBox wbLog.Sheets(I).Name
Next I
```

EDIT: I think I might have useful additional info. It seems that the macro doesn't skip. When I tried to add more entries to the database file, it pulls data, except that it starts at the row where it ended on the previous sheet. For e.g., if it ended on row 9 on sh1, the code starts at row 10 on sh2.

How do I reset the increment before going to the next sheet?

Comment: Add some `Debug.Print` lines within the IF block to indicate that it has been executed (at least to indicate the y and r has incremented). I suspect that the `wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("B" & y).Value = RequiredDate` never resolves True, or only worked once. You should also use `Long` for rows and columns counter.

Comment: check if `wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("B" & y).Value = RequiredDate ` are the same types for comparing

Comment: Hi @PatricK. I did what you suggested and inserted `Debug.Print`, but the increments occur. I also tried changing `For I = 1 to WS_Count`, and started with 2. It still just runs over that first sheet so it seems it resolves True for that sheet.

Comment: Hi @katz, could you explain further what you mean? i'm sorry, i forgot to mention that i'm self-taught so my skill with vba is not complete. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it didn't skip, move the `y = 3` below `For I = 1 To WS_Count` so every sheet starts at row 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the edited code. I opted to add it after the end of the loop, because that way I'd remember it for future reference. Thanks @PatricK!

```
        Dim y As Integer
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim WS_Count As Integer
        Dim I As Integer
        r = CollateSh3.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        y = 3
        WS_Count = wbLog.Worksheets.Count

        For I = 1 To WS_Count
            Do Until wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("A" & y) = ""
            If wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("B" & y).Value = RequiredDate Then

            CollateSh3.Range("A" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("D" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("C" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("F" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("D" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("G" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("E" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("H" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("F" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("I" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("G" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("J" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("H" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("K" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("I" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("L" & y).Value
            CollateSh3.Range("K" & r).Value = wbLog.Sheets(I).Range("N" & y).Value

            r = r + 1
            y = y + 1

            Else
            y = y + 1
            End If
            Loop

            y = 3 'to reset increment before moving on to next sheet

        Next I
```